# Send info and reload page from another view controller without segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I have a tableView(top) and a view controller(bottom) within container views in the same view. I need to send info and refresh the bottom view when selecting a table row. I'd like it to work like the apple stocks app. I originally had the bottom view on another page and used a segue and it worked great. But I'm not sure how to do it without a segue now.

Here is the code for selecting the row:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]

    }
  tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

What I had before for the segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as SNPDetailViewController

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell) {
        controller.itemToEdit = items[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

And what was working when I used the segue in the (now) bottom view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let item = itemToEdit {
        title = item.name
        snpDetails.text = item.details
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table view controller, `self.parentViewController` will point to the container view controller.  Then you can get a reference to the existing detail view controller via the `childViewControllers` property of the container:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        if let vc = self.parentViewController {
            let siblings = vc.childViewControllers
            if siblings.count > 1 {
                if let detailVC = siblings[1] as? SNPDetailViewController {
                    detailVC.itemToEdit = item
                } else {
                    println("Odd, that detail view controller is not the right class")
                    abort()
                }
            } else {
                println("Odd, there is no detail view controller")
                abort()
            }
        } else {
            println("Strange, I'm not embedded in a parent view controller")
            abort()
        }
    }
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

This assumes your table view controller is at index 0 of `childViewControllers`, and the detail view controller is at index 1.  Amend `siblings[1]` to `siblings[0]` if it's the other way around.

You may need to implement a setter method for itemToEdit in order to reload the labels etc when the value changes.

Comment: Thank you! This was the piece I was missing, the parent/child relationship. It seems to be working so far doing it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your bottom view is *SNPDetailViewController*

As you can see in your previous code you had a variable called **controller**. That variable is missing in your actual code. Try to create it in your first snippet of code:

```html
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]

    }
    
    let controller = SNPDetailViewController()
    
    // then you can call the _itemToEdit_ method in your other view
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell) {
        controller.itemToEdit = items[indexPath.row]
    }

  tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

I'm not completely sure if that works but the idea is that you need like an instance of your bottom view to access its methods. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: itemToEdit is a variable. So I need to set it and then refresh SNPDetailViewController somehow.

Comment: So I just called the viewDidLoad method and it worked. Is that the "right" way to reload it? Thanks!

Comment: Ha, I thought it was a method, then yes. I don't know if it's the "right" way but it's how I use to do it.

Comment: So doing it this way is causing all of my iboutlets in SNPDetailViewController to be set to nil. I'm trying to change their text values and such and obviously that's not working now.

Comment: did you set `itemToEdit` first?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the debugger at crash. itemToEdit has values but my outlets are nil.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6741411/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-22%20at%2012.31.30%20PM.png

Comment: @SarahGrady The above is creating a new instance of the controller, not accessing the existing one (hence the IBOutlets not being set).  You need to give your table view controller a pointer to the existing SNPDetailViewController.  The best place to do that is in your container view controller (which is presumably where both table view controller and SNPDetailViewController are instantiated).  Can you post that code?

Comment: @pbasdf I set up the container views and everything in storyboard so there isn't really code. Here's a screenshot of the setup. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6741411/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-22%20at%204.26.50%20PM.png I have code for the entry view and the 2 little views but not the one in the middle. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Can I use a delegate for this? I'm not sure how to set a delegate in this situation since there is no segue.

Comment: @SarahGrady I think you can get away without needing a delegate to pass from the table view to the detail - see my separate answer.  You might still need (or prefer) to use a delegate to pass back from the detail to the table view (if you need to).